# What are some good tips for someone with severe ADHD to learn how to properly search stackoverflow for simple questions?

Tags: search

I'm starting off in computer science! I love it, I love coding, but more importantly, I like knowing how everything works. For example, I wanted to know what exactly "{}" tells my basic GNU SSH shell we use in class. I know where to put it, I know I don't put semi colons after it, and I've written a few VERY basic programs and used this every time, starting with "int main() { //declare variables etc }. My goal is to be able to scour the internet or some material and find answers well.

However, I can't really find to much  on this stuff. My ADHD is an issue, because I'll google  something, and I'll start getting a little  aggravated after searching ww3 schools, etc with no answers or even a certainty I'm looking at the right programming language. Or it appears they're using some updated language with syntax that performs short cuts, or my language is outdated.Websites and resources can't do everything for me. For example, I searched "What does { do in GNU" here  on stackoverflow and came up with nothing. Now I'm sure there's an answer on here. And I'm sure if I spent another 30 minutes searching, I'd find it.

The problem appears to be that I'm not effective in how I search! What keywords, what tools are at my disposal. I see a drop down menu that described a few functions in Stackoverflow, and I've heard the legends from  computer science memes talking about how topics get shut down on here because the answer was an internal search away. When I search for things here, I often find paragraphs of information that appears to be leagues ahead of where I'm at.

How can I search "better"  or at least, more effectively when it comes to programming, and comp sci? This looks like a skill I'm going to need to get good at quick. And given my proffessor has spent the the entirety of each hour long class trying to figure out whats wrong with her internet (She was told shes teaching the class 2 days before it started and is not prepared at all. I would ask her but shes long winded and often goes off track.) I'm going to need to get good at now.

For right now I'm using an OS called GNU on an SSH shell secure server that's hosted on a school computer. I hope I got that right. How can I self-teach myself how to optimize my searches?

Comment: Please note that questions about StackOverflow itself and how to use it should be posted on http://meta.stackoverflow.com, not on the main site.  I've flagged this for migration there.  Normally you have to earn 5 reputation points on the main site before being able to use Meta.

Comment: Thanks! I wasnt aware of that. Exploring more of the site now